# Volume icon not showing in Wingpanel

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, indicator-sound

I had a sound problem after switching volume from internal speakers to HDMI output, so I reset PulseAudio. After which the volume control on the top of the desktop bar (Wingpanel) disappeared. I have tried many ways to restore it though nothing helped. How can I restore the volume indicator?

Answer (score 15):

Enter the following in a terminal.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-sound`

Log out then back in.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helped you by clicking on the checkmark.